# If $G$ is a group, is $G$ isomorphic to $Z(G)\times G/Z(G)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was trying to find a way to prove that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian. Of course there's the usual way of proving it, which appears all over this site, but I wanted to explore a different potential solution a little more. My thought process was that $G/Z(G)$ is sort of like the group of non-commuting elements of $G$, and that any element of $g$ can be expressed as a product of a non-commuting element and a commuting element, i.e. a representative of $G/Z(G)$ times an element of $Z(G)$ (if that makes sense?). However, constructing a well-defined isomorphism has proven to be quite challenging, and I was wondering if there are any counterexamples to this claim or constructions of such isomorphisms? Thanks!

Comment: Your method should take into account that there *are* groups of order $p^3$ which are not Abelian but *all* groups of order $p^2$ are Abelian. (This is for a prime $p$. All groups of order $p^n$ have a non-trivial centre.)

Comment: The claim is false. For example, in the quaternions, $Z(G)=\{1,-1\}$, and $G/Z(G)$ is of exponent $2$. So $Z(G)\times G/Z(G)$ has exponent $2$, but $G$ has elements of order $4$. Use it to see what goes wrong in what you are trying to do.